# How to use people picker for multiple users? SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays, sharepoint

I have created a from and added some textboxed in it, And I have created a people picker which is working good, I can even select multiple users in my field, but if I chose 2 people in peoplepicker in my list is being saved only 1 person. So if I select more than 1 user in people picker like this: [image]

In my list only first name is being saved like this:
[image]

`Audienca` column is a single line of text

How Can I save both users

My people picker code is this:

`My ascx`

```
 <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink4" Name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink5" Name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink6" Name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink7" Name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />


<div id="audienceSelector" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

C# code

```
 initializePeoplePicker('audienceSelector');//this is on top 


function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

// Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['Width'] = '300px';


// Render and initialize the picker. 
// Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
// PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
// picker properties.
SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);

}
```

this is the code when i try to save my data

```
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = quizList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.audienceSelector_TopSpan;
    // Get information about interviewer
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        user = users[0];
        interviewerName = user["DisplayText"];
    }

    listItem.set_item("Title", $('#newTestName').val());
    //listItem.set_item("Audienca", $('#audienceSelector').val().toString());

    listItem.set_item("Audienca", interviewerName);
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you change the users array in your For loop to use [I] instead of [0] like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    user = users[i];
    interviewerName = user["DisplayText"];
}
```

Also I would use a person or group column which will bring more functionality like [presence indicatiors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRzIH.jpg). Make sure that your field on the list is set to allow multiple selections
[in the list settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2FHK.jpg)